# Segmentation fault for no obvious reason

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, arm

I have a segmentation fault that doesn't make any sense to me.
The 538th time this function is called, it fails, but I can see nothing
wrong with the parameters. I can type the same expression to gdb
and it will gladly do it without complaint. I even crept up to it using
si and looked at the registers, and it still doesn't make any sense.
How might I proceed to figure this out?

One strange thing is that gdb reports that the "bit" argument has
changed from 0 to 1 at the fault. 
I suppose "bit" is in a register that got reused for something else.

I also tried this without optimization. There were a lot more instructions
involved, but the result was the same.

Notice below that I use gdb to access the same location that the
code is about to access, with no problem.

Code:

```
void Bits::set(int bit)
{
    if (bit >= _size*16) BUG;
    _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
}
```

gdb run:

```
Breakpoint 1, Bits::set (this=0x68374, bit=0) at util.cpp:181
181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3964c <_ZN4Bits3setEi+36>: ldr     r3, [r0, #4]
(gdb) si
0x00039650      181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x39650 <_ZN4Bits3setEi+40>: mov     r1, #1
(gdb)
0x00039654      181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x39654 <_ZN4Bits3setEi+44>: ldrh    r2, [r12, r3]
(gdb)
0x00039658      181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x39658 <_ZN4Bits3setEi+48>: orr     r2, r2, r1, lsl lr
(gdb)
0x0003965c      181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3965c <_ZN4Bits3setEi+52>: strh    r2, [r12, r3]
(gdb) p _dat
$18 = (short *) 0x4ee74
(gdb) p *_dat
$19 = -3784
(gdb) p $r2
$20 = 61753
(gdb) p $r12
$21 = 0
(gdb) p/x $r3
$22 = 0x4ee74
(gdb) si

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0003965c in Bits::set (this=0x68374, bit=1) at util.cpp:181
181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x3965c <_ZN4Bits3setEi+52>: strh    r2, [r12, r3]
(gdb)
```

By the way, I'm using gdbserver here. Here's the target response:

```
50:/mnt/home/rw # ./gdbserver x:12 cx Andersen_Studio.cxc
Process cx created; pid = 226
Listening on port 12
Remote debugging from host 192.168.1.40

pc : [<0003965c>]    lr : [<00000000>]    Tainted: P
sp : 7ffffdb4  ip : 00000000  fp : 7ffffe84
r10: 2ada7884  r9 : 0000c6c8  r8 : 2ada8d28
r7 : 00000002  r6 : 0005c0b8  r5 : 00000000  r4 : 0006dc10
r3 : 0004ee74  r2 : 0000f139  r1 : 00000001  r0 : 00068374
Flags: Nzcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode USER_32  Segment user
Control: C000317F  Table: 017EC000  DAC: 00000015
```

More information: If I manually do the command, the fault doesn't happen:

```
Breakpoint 1, Bits::set (this=0x6c75c, bit=0) at util.cpp:181
181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
(gdb) c 538
Will ignore next 537 crossings of breakpoint 1.  Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, Bits::set (this=0x68374, bit=0) at util.cpp:181
181         _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
(gdb) p _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15)
$25 = -3783
(gdb) dis 1
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Just referencing _dat[0] doesn't help, but for example typing _dat[0]=0 does prevent the problem.

(edit later)

If we're going to be looking at the code generated for the function, I decided to turn off optimization. Here is the unoptimized code:

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN4Bits3setEi:
   0x0006a1d8 <+0>:     mov     r12, sp
   0x0006a1dc <+4>:     push    {r11, r12, lr, pc}
   0x0006a1e0 <+8>:     sub     r11, r12, #4
   0x0006a1e4 <+12>:    sub     sp, sp, #8
   0x0006a1e8 <+16>:    str     r0, [r11, #-16]
   0x0006a1ec <+20>:    str     r1, [r11, #-20]
=> 0x0006a1f0 <+24>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-16]
   0x0006a1f4 <+28>:    ldr     r3, [r3]
   0x0006a1f8 <+32>:    lsl     r2, r3, #4
   0x0006a1fc <+36>:    ldr     r3, [r11, #-20]
   0x0006a200 <+40>:    cmp     r3, r2
   0x0006a204 <+44>:    blt     0x6a220 <_ZN4Bits3setEi+72>
   0x0006a208 <+48>:    ldr     r0, [pc, #108]  ; 0x6a27c <_ZN4Bits3setEi+164>
   0x0006a20c <+52>:    ldr     r1, [pc, #108]  ; 0x6a280 <_ZN4Bits3setEi+168>
   0x0006a210 <+56>:    mov     r2, #180        ; 0xb4
   0x0006a214 <+60>:    bl      0xa00c <printf>
   0x0006a218 <+64>:    mov     r0, #1
   0x0006a21c <+68>:    bl      0xa09c <exit>
   0x0006a220 <+72>:    ldr     r1, [r11, #-16]
   0x0006a224 <+76>:    ldr     r2, [r11, #-20]
   0x0006a228 <+80>:    asr     r3, r2, #31
   0x0006a22c <+84>:    lsr     r3, r3, #28
   0x0006a230 <+88>:    add     r3, r2, r3
   0x0006a234 <+92>:    asr     r0, r3, #4
   0x0006a238 <+96>:    mov     r3, r0
   0x0006a23c <+100>:   lsl     r2, r3, #1
   0x0006a240 <+104>:   ldr     r3, [r1, #4]
   0x0006a244 <+108>:   add     r12, r2, r3
   0x0006a248 <+112>:   ldr     r1, [r11, #-16]
   0x0006a24c <+116>:   mov     r3, r0
   0x0006a250 <+120>:   lsl     r2, r3, #1
   0x0006a254 <+124>:   ldr     r3, [r1, #4]
   0x0006a258 <+128>:   add     r1, r2, r3
   0x0006a25c <+132>:   ldr     r3, [r11, #-20]
   0x0006a260 <+136>:   and     r2, r3, #15
   0x0006a264 <+140>:   mov     r3, #1
   0x0006a268 <+144>:   lsl     r3, r3, r2
   0x0006a26c <+148>:   ldrh    r2, [r1]
   0x0006a270 <+152>:   orr     r3, r2, r3
   0x0006a274 <+156>:   strh    r3, [r12]
   0x0006a278 <+160>:   ldmdb   r11, {r11, sp, pc}
   0x0006a27c <+164>:   andeq   r8, r8, r0, lsr r12
   0x0006a280 <+168>:   andeq   r8, r8, r4, asr r12
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

I tried inserting _dat[0] = 0; before the "bad" statement, and that caused a fault.
I tried _dat[0]++; and that also faulted.

Comment: So you're saying executing the ARM assembly instruction `strh    r2, [r12, r3]` causes an access violation.  Q: is 0x4ee74 (contained in r3) valid?

Comment: 0x4ee74 is valid. See gdb response $19.

Comment: What's the value of `_size`?  I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Are you using glibc?  It might be worth exporting `MALLOC_CHECK_=3` to have glibc check for malloc related issues.

Comment: Thanks for the full disassembled code.  It is actually easier to read optimized code; but don't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, that all looks OK. You can read from the location, but you cannot write ... strange.

The following ideas spring to my mind:

- Never trust what gdb shows you. When you evaluate an expression in gdb this does something entirely different than what your code does. In particular it will not use your code (unless you call functions by name explicitly). Gdb will use the debug information, which often has gaps and quite some room for interpretation, while your code will use just your code. :-) The values of variables are often wrong in gdb. This is most likely not even gdbs fault. Gdb cannot be better than the debug info generated by the compiler. It even contains lots of heuristics for (debug info related) compiler bugs.
- Many different fault cases may be mapped onto Segfault by your OS. This could for example be an asynchronous data abort, in which case the real problem can be many hundreds of instructions earlier.
- Are you using secure and non-secure memory? Writes to secure memory, through a cache, from non-secure mode may lead to an asynchronous data abort.
- The fact that this function was run 537 times OK does not mean much. Did it run on exactly the same data / memory locations? I mean, the `set()` function is essentially just a memory write. The behavior (crash or not) will always depend on the content of variable 
  `bit`.

When I see strange crashes in my programs which do not make any sense to me I modify the function so it behaves slightly differently. What happens if you do this:

```
void Bits::set(int bit)
{
    if (bit >= _size*16) BUG;
    _dat[bit/16] = 42; // does this crash?
    _dat[0] = 42;      // does this crash?
    _dat[bit/16]++;    // does this crash?
    _dat[bit/16] |= 1 << (bit & 15);
}
```

(You might need to save / restore the locations written if your program depends on this.)

What also helps is to print diagnostic messages from the program into some log. This is often better than using a debugger since this uses your code and actual values rather than using debug info.

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out why there is a segmentation fault at this particular line, since there seems to be no problem modifying the memory using gdb. However, by printing out "this" in the Bits constructor, and comparing it to "this" at the fault, I see that I must be suffering from memory corruption, probably somewhere far away from here. Thus, I am going to break off from this line of investigation and carry on assuming that the problem is elsewhere.

(later)

I found the problem, which was an uninitialized pointer (surprise!) to Bits that just happened to be believable enough that it looked superficially as if it was correct. The idea that pointed me in the right direction was the "logging things" idea, which I just did with printf.

Comment: And also compiling (with a recent GCC compiler e.g. 4.8) with `-Wall -Wextra` might help also..

Answer (score -1):

1) So you're saying executing the ARM assembly instruction strh r2, [r12, r3] causes an access violation.

2) Q: is 0x4ee74 (contained in r3) valid?

3) Q: is 0000f139 (contained in r2) valid?  From the manual:

> http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABDJCHA.html
>
> **Address alignment for word and halfword transfers:**
>
> The address must be a multiple of 4.
>
> If your system has a system coprocessor (cp15), you can enable
>   alignment checking. Non-aligned transfers cause an alignment exception
>   if alignment checking is enabled.
>
> If your system does not have a system coprocessor (cp15), or alignment
>   checking is disabled:
>
> A non-aligned load corrupts Rd.
>
> A non-aligned save corrupts four bytes in memory. The corrupted location in memory is [address AND NOT b11].

Comment: Since the load two instructions earlier does _not_ fail, it would seem the address is valid, but the memory is write protected.

Comment: The address IS a multiple of 4. The contents of r2 should be a don't-care. We're just storing whatever it is.

Comment: If the memory were write protected, wouldn't gdb have trouble writing to it? and how did it suddenly get write protected? Note that it is non-zero, which means that this same function has already accessed this location in some of its 537 previous calls.